# Regex, exclude filename in html

Tags: php, html, regex

Html Code

```
<div class="thx_thanked_post"><a title="Click to enlarge" target="_blank" data-fancybox="data-2581" data-type="image" href="images/thx/star.png"><img src="images/thx/star.png" alt="Better response on post dqwdqwdqwqdwdqwqwdwdwd" class="thx_thanked_post_img"></a>Just a "quick" overview of what's good and why.<br>

<a title="Click to enlarge" target="_blank" data-fancybox="data-2581" data-type="image" href="images/thx/kek.png"><img src="images/thx/kek.png" alt="Better response on post dqwdqwdqwqdwdqwqwdwdwd" class="thx_thanked_post_img"></a>
<br>
Note: Hyper speed is referenced multiple times here. This is a bug(?) where after reaching speeds over 160 km/h, you continue accelerating like crazy while traveling in a straight line, allowing you to reach speeds of over 500 km/h with a good boost under ideal conditions. Making good use of hyper speed when possible is huge for cutting time, and much of what makes something good is how easily and consistently it works to give hyper speed.<br>
```

I want to exclude `<img>` tag that has "stars.png", enclosed by `<a>` tag.

My regex:

```
<a [^>]*\>([\t]|[\n])*<img[^>]*^(?!.*star\.png$)[^>]*\>([\t]|[\n])*<\/a>
```

It doesn't work. This picks up nothing.
Correct match should only pickup 2nd `<a>` tag with `<img>` that has "images/thx/kek.png" but not "images/thx/star.png".

Comment: JavaScript? Python? PHP? Add the applicable tag to post.

Comment: @zer00ne it's php, sorry. but basically i am testing on https://regex101.com/r/R3P1eF/1

Comment: In that [test](https://regex101.com/r/EAb7fK/1/) there isn't any text that is even close to `star`. Just remove that regex and type in *star* and there's no matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a [^>]*>([\t]|[\n])*<img(?!.*star\.png)[^>]*>([\t]|[\n])*<\/a>` seems to work.

`^` and `$` match the start and the end of the line, and they are likely not what you want to match, so I remove them. `[^>]*` matches all the content in `img` tag and stops just before the closing `>`. Lookahead assertion `(?!.*star\.png)` after it starts matching from that `>` and not the content in `img` tag, so I move it in front of `[^>]*`.